# exposing Azure DNS servers

Tags: azure, dns, iaas

I have an Azure virtual machine with multiple web sites on it that I would like to expose to the Internet.  The VM has Active Directory and DNS installed on it.  I created the forward zone (xxx.cloudapp.net) on my server, and added the two web site names to the zone. On the Networks in the Management Portal, I added a DNS server(xxx.cloudapp.net) and gave it the public IP for my server.

So when I try a nslookup from outside of the VM, the names will not resolve.  I set the server in nslookup to either the public IP or the name, and it does not resolve.  I have logging turned on in the DNS server, but it does not seem to show any requests from my computer.

I must be doing something wrong.  Any suggestions?  This server is for a demo next week, and worst case, I can buy a couple of domain names.

Comment: You'd need to ensure that the Windows Firewall was configured to allow inbound DNS requests from other hosts (this will allow private access). For public access you will also need to check that you have the necessary Endpoints open on the cloud service which is hosting the server.

Comment: Did you resolve this problem? cause i'm on exactly the same situation. If you do, please post an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the instance level public-ip address, you will get an ip address per virtual server: https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-instance-level-public-ip/